# "built in dependency injection" in scala

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection

Hi the following post says there is "built in dependency injection" in scala

> "As a Scala and Java developer, I am not even slightly tempted to
>   replace Scala as my main language for my next project with Java 8. If
>   I'm forced to write Java, it might better be Java 8, but if I have a
>   choice, there are so many things (as the OP correctly states) that
>   make Scala compelling for me beyond Lambdas that just adding that
>   feature to Java doesn't really mean anything to me. Ruby has Lambdas,
>   so does Python and JavaScript, Dart and I'm sure any other modern
>   language. I like Scala because of so many other things other than
>   lambdas that a single comment is not enough.
>
> But to name a few (some were referenced by the OP)
>
> Everything is an expression, For
>   comprehensions (especially with multiple futures, resolving the
>   callback triangle of death in a beautiful syntax IMHO), Implicit
>   conversions, Case classes, Pattern Matching, Tuples, The fact that
>   everything has equals and hashcode already correctly implemented (so I
>   can put a tuple, or even an Array as a key in a map), string
>   interpolation, multiline string, default parameters, named parameters,
>   **built in dependency injection**, most complex yet most powerful type
>   system in any language I know of, type inference (not as good as
>   Haskell, but better than the non existent in Java). The fact I always
>   get the right type returned from a set of "monadic" actions thanks to
>   infamous things like CanBuildFrom (which are pure genius). Let's not
>   forget pass by name arguments and the ability to construct a DSL.
>   Extractors (via pattern matching). And many more.
>
> I think Scala is
>   here to stay, at least for Scala developers, I am 100% sure you will
>   not find a single Scala developer that will say: "Java 8 got lambdas?
>   great, goodbye scala forever!". Only reason I can think of is compile
>   time and binary compatibility. If we ignore those two, all I can say
>   is that this just proves how Scala is in the right direction (since
>   Java 8 lambdas and default interface methods and steams are so clearly
>   influenced)
>
> I do wish however that Scala will improve Java 8
>   interoperability, e.g. support functional interfaces the same way. and
>   add new implicit conversions to Java 8 collections as well as take
>   advantage to improvements in the JVM.
>
> I will replace Scala as soon as
>   I find a language that gives me what Scala does and does it better. So
>   far I didn't find such a language (examined Haskell, Clojure, Go,
>   Kotlin, Ceylon, Dart, TypeScript, Rust, Julia, D and Nimrod, Ruby
>   Python, JavaScript and C#, some of them were very promising but since
>   I need a JVM language, and preferably a statically typed one, it
>   narrowed down the choices pretty quickly)
>
> Java 8 is by far not even
>   close, sorry. Great improvement, I'm very happy for Java developers
>   that will get "permission" to use it (might be easier to adopt than
>   Scala in an enterprise) but this is not a reason for a Scala shop to
>   consider moving back to Java." [[1](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7478367)]

what is exactly the `built in dependency injection` in `scala`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would one do dependency injection in scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563929/how-would-one-do-dependency-injection-in-scala)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a discrete language feature. I think the author was referring to the fact that Scala's feature set is flexible enough to support a number of techniques that could be said to accomplish DI:

- [the cake pattern](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf), building on the trait system
- [the Reader monad](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2013/10/21/reader-monad-for-dependency-injection/), building on higher-kinded types
- [DI through currying](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio), building on functional techniques
- [using implicit class parameters](http://carefulescapades.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-implicit-parameters-for.html?m=1), building on Scala's concept of implicits
- in my own project, we accomplish DI by requiring function values in the class constructor explicitly

This diversity is rather emblematic of Scala. The language was designed to implement a number of very powerful concepts, mostly orthogonally, resulting in multiple valid ways to solve many problems. The challenge as a Scala programmer is to understand this breadth and then make an intelligent choice for your project. A lot of times, that choice depends on what paradigms are being used internally to implement your components.

Comment: I think the 4th approach, using implicit class parameters, is much like saying "pass the dependencies as class arguments". The implicits only reduce code bloat a little, and opens up for flexibility about where the dependency will come from (caller's implicit, import, etc).

Comment: Actually, I think they have the tendency to not really impact code bloat when used for dependencies, since the only place they don't need to be mentioned is the call site, but you need to tag `implicit` everywhere else, to pass them along our consume them. I actually do use them though for passing library dependencies, in the Akka style of having an implicit actor system, etc. But then I make my API functions explicit. This seems to provide a nice distinction between infrastructure and data dependencies.